# Migrate git repo to another repo's submodule

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a git repository and I would like to migrate it to another one, but to its submodule. Is it possible? 
It's due to having repo for Frontend and Backend separately and now, I would like to migrate it to one common repo, where I would like to store both together, but in two seperate submodules.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: In what sense of the word "submodules"? `git submodules`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this repo "as is" and use it as a sub-repo in your "master repo":

https://github.com/git-commands/git-subrepo